# Finding best match by minMaxLoc returned values OpenCV with a specific level of thershold

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I want to find best match by a level of threshold.

Here is what i did but the values are staying at 0.

```
cvMatchTemplate(src, tmp, result, CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED);
CvPoint minLoc = new CvPoint();
CvPoint maxLoc = new CvPoint();
DoublePointer min_val = new DoublePointer();
DoublePointer max_val = new DoublePointer();

cvMinMaxLoc(result,min_val, max_val, minLoc, maxLoc, null);
```

I don't really get the double pointers but it was required by the mothode.
min_value and max_value are staying at zero so i cant find the best matches.

Thanks in advanced.Using javaCV.

Answer (score 0):

In the example [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/30365/javacv-template-matching-improper-if-region-set-using-cvsetimageroi/) they used primitive doubles, not Double type and they defined arrays, not just objects. So, why don't you give it a shot and let us know if it would make any difference.

```
cvMatchTemplate(src, tmp, result, CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED);

double[] min_val = new double[2];
double[] max_val = new double[2];
CvPoint minLoc = new CvPoint();
CvPoint maxLoc = new CvPoint();

cvMinMaxLoc(result, min_val, max_val, minLoc, maxLoc,null);
```

**__UPDATE__**

I found the following code from [here](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/samples/TemplateMatching.java)

```
// Match Template Function from OpenCV
cvMatchTemplate(src, tmp, result, CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED);

// double[] min_val = new double[2];
// double[] max_val = new double[2];
DoublePointer min_val = new DoublePointer();
DoublePointer max_val = new DoublePointer();

CvPoint minLoc = new CvPoint();
CvPoint maxLoc = new CvPoint();

cvMinMaxLoc(result, min_val, max_val, minLoc, maxLoc, null);
```

Pay attention to how they instantiated DoublePointer() **without any params**. If it does not help, I am not sure what this thing is about. I hope it works.

Comment: It just wont let me do that : "The method cvMinMaxLoc(opencv_core.CvArr, DoublePointer, DoublePointer, opencv_core.CvPoint, opencv_core.CvPoint, opencv_core.CvArr) in the type opencv_core is not applicable for the arguments (opencv_core.IplImage, double[], double[], opencv_core.CvPoint, opencv_core.CvPoint, null)"

Comment: hmm.May be the version you are using is different than the one they used in the example. Can you find and share out the version of javaCV please ?

Comment: Im using version 0.11

Comment: Nope . i syso before and after the minMax and its the same.

Comment: Sorry. I ran out of ideas then. :( Good luck.